FormBuilder doesn't seem to send Activity Notifications
My ultimate goal is to have our internal staff member notified when someone submits a particular FormBuilder form.
I have activity notifications set up properly. They work fine when an activity is added from the CiviCRM admin pages.
FormBuilder form seems to be working as expected: the individual and activity are created properly, and the activity is assigned properly.
But strangely, no email arrives and there's no "email" activity added. When I do a manual addition with the same values as the FormBuilder values, the email goes out.
So it seems like FormBuilder is not triggering activity notification.
If anyone has suggestions about how to debug, I'd appreciate it!
I'm also going to try to do this with Rules, but it seems like activity notifications should work based on what I see here: FormBuilder submission and add to group
Details:

The person submitting the form in not logged in - anonymous user, but for testing purposes I tried using an existing user's contact information with an internal email address so that there shouldn't be any issues with emails not going out/being received because of spam filters or something.  That same person is the "Added" "With" & "Assigned to" person

Using form-based security, not user security if that matters

This site runs on Joomla, not drupal.




I wonder if that other post is correct about the setting on the misc tab working. I know from civi's history that a certain amount of "business logic" lives in the quickform code and so only works when using the quickforms, and the sending of the activity email is one of them, so unless there is also specific code in formbuilder/api4 to do so, it probably shouldn't work. Might be worth asking the formbuilder (afform) channel in chat.civicrm.org where the formbuilder people hang out.

Thank you.  Trying there.

Link to Chat which currently seems to conclude that this feature isn't available and to use CiviRules: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/p3c3ed88ffbmdgwrb6mte854ra
